# button to add a marker to google-maps not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```js
   Long = -40.00;
    Lati = 150.00;
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng( Long, Lati),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });
    
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng( Long, Lati),
  map: map
 });
    
    function AddMarker() {
     var Long = document.getElementById('longitude').value;
        var Lati = document.getElementById('latitude').value;
        
        var map = google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng( Long, Lati),
   map: map
  });
    }
```

```html
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<div>
 Long :<input type="text" id="longitude" size="10" value="-40.20">
    Lati :<input type="text" id="latitude" size="10" value="150.00">
    <input type="submit" onclick="AddMarker()" value="Add">
</div>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
```

Hi
The button to add one more marker is not working, any ideia why ?
if i use the "new" on the var map variable it will work but it will create and clear the mark that is there already.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how the code should look like, I removed this line of code which is unnecessary :

> var map = google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));

JS:

```
    var Long = -40.00;
    var Lati = 150.00;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng( Long, Lati),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });



function AddMarker() {
        Long = document.getElementById('longitude').value;
        Lati = document.getElementById('latitude').value;


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng( Long, Lati),
            map: map
        });
    }
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wexd3spp/8/

Comment: Hi... ahhh you removed as well the init marker, cause it was no sense to me thatthere but it was not working<br>Well thanks...